# C# ALL functions and methods throw an exception

Tags: c#

Literally, no matter what the function/method is, it will always crash the game.
I have two projects, one for UI and one for Engine.
The UI contains a Forms application. The Engine contains a World.cs static class. If I ever try to reference a function/method (but not a variable) from the World, it will Throw an exception. I even made a function:

```
public static void Potato()
{
    int pot;
    pot = 0;
}
```

in the World.cs, and in the CoreUI.cs (forms application) referenced it:

```
World.Potato();
```

and it threw an exception. It only throws an exception with the World class. I have two other public static classes that I can reference with no exception thrown. Can anyone explain what is happening? And if I need to provide more code, I will. Thanks!

World.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Engine
{
    public static class World
    {
    public static readonly int[] world;
    public const int worldSize = 20;

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    //Constructor
    static World()
    {
        GenerateWorld();
    }
    private static void GenerateWorld()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < worldSize-2; i += 1)
        {
            world[i] = ChooseLandType(rand.NextDouble());
        }
        world[0] = 0;
        world[19] = 4;
    }
    private static int ChooseLandType(double a)
    {
        if (a <= 0.5d) return 0;
        else if (a > 0.5d && a <= 0.55d) return 1;
        else if (a > 0.55d && a <= 0.8d) return 2;
        else if (a > 0.8d && a <= 0.9d) return 3;
        else if (a > 0.9d) return 4;
        else return 0;
    }
    public static int GetLocationType(int a)
    {
        if (a < worldSize) return world[a];
        else return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Relevant Code in CoreUI.cs:

```
private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _player.MoveTo(_player.Y + 1);
        float a = (100f * (_player.Y / 20f));
        a = Clampf(a,0,100);
        pbPos.Value = (int)a;
        //The next line is the Thrown Exception
        pBoxIMG.Image = GetImage(World.GetLocationType(_player.Y));
    }
```

Exception Detail Copied to Clipboard:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'Engine.World' threw an exception.
  Source=Engine
  TypeName=Engine.World
  StackTrace:
       at Engine.World.GetLocationType(Int32 a)
       at SomeProgram.CoreUI.btnForward_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeProgram\SomeProgram\CoreUI.cs:line 43
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at SomeProgram.Program.Main() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeProgram\SomeProgram\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       HResult=-2147467261
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=Engine
       StackTrace:
            at Engine.World.GenerateWorld() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeProgram\Engine\World.cs:line 23
            at Engine.World..cctor() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeProgram\Engine\World.cs:line 17
       InnerException:
```

Simplified:

> The type initializer for 'Engine.World' threw an exception.

Comment: you need to provide more code. Does it crash with Tomatoes as well? :-)

Comment: Start with providing the exception that gets thrown

Comment: @buffjape that was hilarious

Comment: Sounds like an exception in the static initializer - either when initializing static fields or in a static constructor. What's the exception, and where is it thrown? What's the inner exceptions?

Comment: what happens when you debug it?

Comment: More information needed.. but you could start checking you static methods for errors.. the code posted here is irrelevant

Comment: `world = new world[worldSize];` in constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't initialize `world`

So you need to add

```
static World()
{
    world = new int[worldSize];
    GenerateWorld();
}
```

Comment: Typing that exactly gives " 'Engine.World.world' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' "

Comment: It's an array of integers: world = new int[worldSize]

Comment: Yeah I've been awake for around 30 hours now so I can't think straight. Seems extremely simple now that I think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anixias ok that explains it. You need sleep, not stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the initial method you've shown, so the problem is in another part of the code.

In the class you've shown, there is a static constructor:

```
class World
{
    // ...

    static World()
    {
        GenerateWorld();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Static constructors (and static initializers) may be executed lazily - that is, whenever you first use that particular class. If they run fine, then there's no problem and you don't even notice them.

But if they happen to throw an exception for any reason, it would appear (during debugging) as if *your method* threw it. But in fact your initial method is innocent - it simply caused the CLR to run the actual culprit method while it was loading that particular class.

In other words, the exception is being thrown from the `GenerateWorld()` method. As others have said, it is because you are indexing an array:

```
world[i] = // ...
```

But you haven't initialized the array first:

```
world = new int[worldSize];
```

Comment: Yeah, I get errors if I don't put static before every single variable/method.

Comment: @Anixias The problem isn't that these are `static`. The problem is that they run when you don't expect them, and they cause your `NullReferenceException` (because you haven't initialized the array `world`). Although, incidentally, if you don't know when/why you should/shouldn't mark something as `static`, I'd suggest that you first do some further reading on what exactly it is (as it will help you avoid some other kinds of errors).

Comment: Oh okay I get it now! Thanks!